# Count unique items that contains specific combination of data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a pandas dataframe to give me information on a rather large csv. I want to find how many unique IDs contain the specific associations. What I am trying to find is shown below. I know this can likely be done on a single line using pandas, but I cannot figure out the right combination of syntax to get the data I want.

I have tried using groupby('ID')['Associations'] on the dataframe but I cannot figure out how to give me the number of ID's that hold the combinations. such as the example provided below

```py
csv = pd.read_csv('export.csv', delimiter=",")
print(csv)

      ID  Associations
      1   "AA"
      1   "BB"
      1   "CC"
      2   "AA"
      3   "BB"
      4   "CC"
      5   "AA"
      5   "BB"
      6   "AA"
      6   "CC"
      7   "CC"
      7   "BB"
      7   "AA"
```

So when I look for specific combinations, such as ["AA","BB","CC"] or ["AA, CC"], it would give me counts such as

```py
give_counts(["AA,"BB","CC"])
>> 2
# Because IDs 1 and 7 have "AA","BB", and"CC"
give_counts(["AA,"CC"])
>> 3 
# Because IDs 1,6, and 7 has "AA", and "CC" 
give_counts(["AA"])
>> 5
# Because IDs 1,2,5,6, and 7 has "AA"
```

So basically, I am looking for how many unique ID's are associated with that combination of data. I know this involves using groupby() but I don't know how to take it from there.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

- This is one way you can go from.
- first group by `ID` to aggregate `Associations` columns.
- First sort and then combine this `Associations` for counting.
- `value_counts` gives you count of each combinations.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7] ,'Associations':['AA','BB','CC','AA','CC','AA','CC','BB']})
temp = df.groupby('ID')['Associations'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
temp.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
AABBCC    2
AACC      1
Name: Associations, dtype: int64
```

- You can also retrieve which `ID` for which combination from this

```
>>>temp
ID
1    AABBCC
2      AACC
7    AABBCC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def give_count(lst):
    return df.groupby('ID')['Associations'].apply(lambda x: all((x == i).any() for i in lst)).sum()

print(give_count(['"AA"']))
print(give_count(['"AA"','"CC"']))
print(give_count(['"AA"','"BB"','"CC"']))
```

Output:

```
5
3
2
```

Comment: Hi, I think this does what I want it to. Is there a method for doing this if the data set is in the hundreds of thousands of rows? I am working with a csv that is 288,000 rows long, with thousands of unique IDs and dozens of unique Associations

Comment: Hrm... not a single method that I am aware of.  However, I am sure this could be optimized using numpy.

Comment: I guess that would be my next question, how would I do this in numpy? As well as a question of whether this will count things that are doubled. Like if ID #1 had "AA", "BB", and "AA", and I ran a give_count("AA"), would ID#1 still count for only 1, or would it count for 2? Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: This answer should still only give a count of 1 in ID if "AA" appeared twice.  I think.